# What variable dictates position of non-focused elements in the roundabout plugin?

Tags: jquery, positioning

I'm using the roundabout plugin to cycle through 3 divs. Each div is 794px wide, which makes the roundabout-in-focus element 794 and the two not in focus 315.218px wide, positioned so half of each is hidden by the in-focus div. This is all well and good, however the total width of the display needs to stay within 1000px (ideally 980px, but i can fudge if need be.)

Basically I want to make the non-focused divs be 3/4 hidden by the in-focus div but for the life of me can't figure out what variables i need to edit in order to do it. Unfortunately it's not one of the many easily-changed options like z-index and minScale. i tried minScale but it's clear this isn't going to work.

the plugin outputs this code:

`<li class="roundabout-moveable-item" style="position: absolute; left: -57px; top: 205px; width: 319.982px; height: 149.513px; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 146; font-size: 5.6px;">`

i need to find out what changes the left positioning so it's shifted closer to the center of the stage, like this:

`<li class="roundabout-moveable-item" style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 205px; width: 319.982px; height: 149.513px; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 146; font-size: 5.6px;">`

i tried playing with the positioning functions of the plugin but all that did was shift everything in tandem left or right.

any help is greatly appreciated. this site is going to be awesome once i figure out all this jquery stuff!

here is a link to my .js file: http://avalon.eaw.com/scripts/jquery.roundabout2.js i've got an overflow:hidden on the  to help guide the positioning of those no-focused items.

Comment: anyone? there has to be a way...

Comment: anything in the rules saying how many times i can bump this? with only 21 views i'm sure it just isn't visible. *fingers crossed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same problem myself and tweaked the options suggested above but had no joy. I reset these options back to default and tweaked the following options and I was able to get it to fit in my 980px container:

```
info.midStage = {
    width: info.stage.width / 2.69,
    //original value was 2.0 - changed to resize the item and move it closer to the middle
    height: info.stage.height / 2
    };

    info.nudge = {
    width: info.midStage.width + (info.stage.width * 0.18),
    //original value was 0.05 - changed to resize the item and move it closer to the middle
    height: info.midStage.height + (info.stage.height * 0.05)
    };
```

Hopefully this helps you or anyone else with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Adjusting the width/height settings of the roundabout ul should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't think I've found the ideal solution, but without any guidance I just started hacking away at the scripts, changing numbers here and there to see what happened. I was able to get the flanking elements closer to the center by modifying the math, like so:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict";

    var defaults, internalData, methods;

    // add default shape
    $.extend({
        roundaboutShapes: {
            def: "lazySusan",
            lazySusan: function (r, a, t) {
                return {
                    x: Math.sin(r + a), 
                    y: (Math.sin(r + 3*Math.PI/2 + a) / 8) * t, 
                    z: (Math.cos(r + a) + 1) / 2,
                    scale: (Math.sin(r + Math.PI/2 + a) / 1.5) + 0.5 // default setting a) / 2.0) changed to bring out of focus elements closer to the middle
                };
            }
        }
    });
```

and to adjust the tilt (that wasn't responding at all to the predefined var) i modified the defined css for 'top'

```
// update item
child
    .css({
        left: ((factors.x * info.midStage.width + info.nudge.width) - factors.width / 2.0).toFixed(0) + "px",
        top: ((factors.y * info.midStage.height + info.nudge.height) - factors.height / 1.3).toFixed(0) + "px",
        // default setting is factors.height / 2.0. changed to adjust height ratio of in focus and out of focus items
        width: factors.width + "px",
        height: factors.height + "px",
        opacity: (info.opacity.min + (info.opacity.diff * factors.scale)).toFixed(2),
        zIndex: Math.round(info.zValues.min + (info.zValues.diff * factors.z)),
        fontSize: (factors.adjustedScale * data.startFontSize).toFixed(1) + "px"
    });
    data.currentScale = factors.adjustedScale;
```

I hope this helps someone. I know there has to be a better way to do it, so if anyone finds the answer please post it!